# Kaltura Player Error: “Source Video Not Found” even though Status is “ready”

Tags: c#, angular, web, kaltura, kaltura-player

I’m having an issue with the Kaltura player in my application. We’re using the KalturaClient to fetch video information from the Kaltura server. Although the KalturaEntryStatus response object shows that the video status is 2 so “ready”, inside the Kaltura player I’m receiving a “No source was found” error. This is happening even though the video is playable in the Kaltura admin panel.

All the different flavors of the video are also marked as “ready” and loaded in the admin panel, but it’s still not playable inside the Kaltura player.

I suspect that the issue might be related to caching. It’s possible that the video is taking longer to convert and that it’s being cached somewhere along the way, causing the player to display an error. However, I’m not certain how to resolve this issue.

Can anyone provide any insights or solutions to this problem?

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions you can provide.

Best regards,
dtz

Comment: Maybe KS/entry permission are not enough? If the entry is playing in thr admin panel then it is probably not a video issue. Did you tried different player? Can you please share stand alone page link?